# Azure Search Client not working for dash (-)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-sdk-.net

If I try to search `/.*mydata-mydepartment.*/` directly in portal.azure.com using Search Explorer I'm getting correct data , But when I tried same search text from C# .NET API it is giving no result.

Using nuget Azure Search Document 11.4.0, below method to fetch search result:

```
public async virtual Task<Response<SearchResults<T>>> SearchAsync<T>(
            string searchText,
            SearchOptions options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) =>
            await SearchInternal<T>(
                searchText,
                options,
                async: true,
                cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Why it's not working with .net code? What needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following:

```
/.*mydata-mydepartment.*/
```

Is a Regular Expression, and it's only available if you specify the search mode as all and query type to full. (Inside SearchOptions which currently you're setting as null)

```
"queryType": "full",
"search": "/.*mydata-mydepartment.*/",
"searchMode": "all"
```

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_regex

Comment: its strange its not working with regular expression after using all above but its working without regular expression if i give only like "mydata-mydepartment". why or which one i need to use when pls guide? thanks in advance,

Comment: the way you specified it's a regular expression and you should use the way I've shared.